# Using if else statement based off of $_POST value to echo message

Tags: php, forms

Pretty sure this is a quick and easy question but I have a form that on action POST goes to a confirmation page. I need a message to display on the confirmation page if the user selects county1 but if user selects county2, county3, or county4. However, when I setup the statement it's not working. Probably a syntax error or two on my part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A messy idea of what I think should work:

```
<?php $county=$_POST['County']; 
if ($county="Polk") {
echo "Important message about your county"; }
else {
echo " "; // Or nothing at all
}
?>
```

But

```
<?php echo $_POST['County'] ?>
```

displays the name of the county so I know the submission is carrying through. Thoughts on why my above code wouldn't be working? If you could flag  syntax errors or code placement that'd be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the if condition you should use two equal operators instead of one . try this code

```
<?php
    $county = isset($_POST['County'])?$_POST['County']:""; 
    if ($county == "Polk") {
        echo "Important message about your county";
    }
    else {
        echo " "; // Or nothing at all
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use double equal in your if statement for comparison**
 See the answer and read the comment to understand why you have to change it

```
if ($county="Polk") {
```

Single equal is assignment operator, it assign value

Change this line to this

```
if ($county=="Polk") {
```

So your whole code should look like this

```
 $county=$_POST['County'];
if ($county == "Polk") {
        echo "Important message about your county";
    }
    else {
        echo " "; // Or nothing at all
    }
```

Use double equal sign, double equal is comparison operator, 
Here you are checking if the $county is equal to Polk or not, 
Means you are comparing value